# issue with sns email getting just one parameter

Tags: json, python-3.x, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

I have written this code in lambda in python to get just the dimensions in the email

```
import boto3
import json

sns_arn = "arn:awsid"

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  client = boto3.client("sns")
  resp = client.publish(TargetArn=sns_arn,Message=json.dumps(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']), Subject="Subject")
```

So in the email i get this values

> {"AlarmName":"test","AlarmDescription":null,"AWSAccountId":"test","NewStateValue":"ALARM","NewStateReason":"Threshold Crossed: 1 datapoint [0.39611629881148863 (06/03/19 10:22:00)] was greater than or equal to the threshold (0.0).", "StateChangeTime":"2", "Region":"test","OldStateValue":"INSUFFICIENT_DATA","Trigger":"MetricName":"CPUUtilization","Namespace":"AWS/EC2","StatisticType":"Statistic","Statistic":"AVERAGE","Unit":null,**"Dimensions":[{"value":"i-test","name":"InstanceId"}],**"Period":300,"EvaluationPeriods":1,"ComparisonOperator":"GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold","Threshold":0.0,"TreatMissingData":"\","EvaluateLowSampleCountPercentile":"\"}}

My requirement is to get only the highlighted values. Please let me know if you have any solution ?

Comment: I can't see any highlighting, please edit the question to format your code and output properly, and to sort out the highlighting so that the community can help you. Thanks.

Comment: What's the highlighted value that you want to send? Remember that for example if you want to show the StateChangeTime value you only need add StateChangeTime to the line -> event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']['StateChangeTime']

Comment: I am sorry for that earlier. I have highlighted the code. My requirement is to get "Dimensions":[{"value":"i-test","name":"InstanceId"